# WxPython Pango error after clicking on wx.SpinCtrl

Tags: wxwidgets, wxpython

The actual error is produced by a much larger program I've been writing, but the following sample reproduces the error:

```
import wx

class MyLine(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.thickness = 1
        self.length = 10
        self.spin_ctrl = []

        super(MyLine, self).__init__(None)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.ColourDatabase().Find("GREY"))
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        #Length section
        self.spin_ctrl.append(wx.SpinCtrl(self, initial = self.length, min    = 1, max = 100))
        vbox.Add(self.spin_ctrl[-1], 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)

        #Thickness section
        self.spin_ctrl.append(wx.SpinCtrl(self, initial = self.thickness, min = 1, max = 10))
        vbox.Add(self.spin_ctrl[-1], 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(vbox)
        self.Show()

app = wx.App()

fr = MyLine()
app.MainLoop()
```

When the above is run, a window appears with two `SpinCtrl` buttons. If I click on the first one to change the value and then close the window, everything works fine and there are no error messages. When I click on the second button to change its value and then close the window, the following error appears:
`Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_get_cursor_pos: assertion 'index >= 0 && index <= layout->length' failed`. Is this a bug or am I not using `SpinCtrl` buttons correctly?

I am running `WxPython4.0.3`.

Comment: Which version of GTK+ do you use?

Comment: Hi, it's libgtk-3-dev 3.22.11-1. I am on Debian 9.

Comment: Strange, I can't reproduce this with exactly the same GTK+ version (also under Debian Stretch) using the same code from C++, so I can't say where do these message come from, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I have tested the above on two machines, the second being a brand new Stretch install and they both produce the same error. I am using a pip installation of wxpython, I'm wondering if that's breaking something on Debian.

Comment: If it helps, I don't think these warnings are as critical as that. Something seems to try to index beyond the end of the string, but failing. Of course, it shouldn't happen and I'd like to debug it and find why and where it does, but it's not the end of the world neither...